# Moving an object towards your cursor at a certain velocity Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am struggling as to how to move an object towards your cursor at a **certain velocity** in Javascript. Here is my code:

```
var topp1 = document.getElementById("top");
var bottom = document.getElementById("bottom");

document.onmousemove = function(){
    var a = event.clientX * 100 / window.innerWidth + "%";
    console.log("a: " + a);
    var b = event.clientY * 100 / window.innerHeight - 36 + "%";
    console.log("b: " + b);

    

    
    for(var i=0;i<2;i++){
        topp1.style.left = a;
        topp1.style.top = b;
        
        bottom.style.left = a;
        bottom.style.top = b;
        
    }
    

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use jQuery and do something like this.
Play around with the transition time in css to change "speed".

```js
$(document).on("click mousemove",".box",function(e){ 
var x = e.clientX;
var y = e.clientY;
var newposX = x - 60;
var newposY = y - 60; $(".circle").css("transform","translate3d("+newposX+"px,"+newposY+"px,0px)");
});
```

```css
body{
  margin:0px;
  padding:0px;
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
}
.box{
  width:100%;
  height:500px;
  background:#eaeaea;
  position:relative;
  overflow:hidden;
  cursor:crosshair;
}

.circle{
  background:#f00;
  width:120px;
  height:120px;
  border-radius:50%;
  position:absolute;
  
  transform:translate3d(-50%,-50%,0);
  transition:transform 2s cubic-bezier(.02,1.23,.79,1.08);
}


i{
  color:#f00;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="box">
  <div class="circle"></civ>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

`onmousemove` is an event. By using the `=` you are redefining the `document.onmousemove` function. What you should be doing is assigning a callback to it.

```
var topp1 = document.getElementById("top");
var bottom = document.getElementById("bottom");

document.onmousemove((event) => {
    var a = event.clientX * 100 / window.innerWidth + "%";
    console.log("a: " + a);
    var b = event.clientY * 100 / window.innerHeight - 36 + "%";
    console.log("b: " + b);

    for(var i=0;i<2;i++){
        topp1.style.left = a;
        topp1.style.top = b;
        
        bottom.style.left = a;
        bottom.style.top = b;
    }
}
```

Here's a good read on callbacks: [MDN Callback function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Callback_function)